# Make an object in two child views equal

Tags: java, android

I have two view classes, `HitOrMiss` and `PlaceShips`, that extend a class, `BuildGame`. BuildGame has an object, `mGame`. At runtime 2 instances of mGame are created, one for each child class. mGame contains a list of listeners among other things, however HitOrMiss and PlaceShips only add their listeners to their own instances of mGame. As a result the individual views only update when you tap on that specific one.

Essentially I am trying to set the mGame of one of the views to the mGame of the other, so that will just update the reference to the same object, but I can't figure out how! Setting mGame to `static` does work, however, my lecturer for this unit has said there is another way without using static and i'd lose marks, which is fair enough.

BuildGame:

```
public class BuildGame extends View {
protected final BaseSubClass mGame = new BaseSubClass(10, 10, BattleshipGameBase.ShipData.CREATOR.newArray(5));
private Paint mGridPaint, mPlayer1Paint, mPlayer2Paint, mBGPaint, mHitPaint, mMissPaint;
protected float diameterX, diameterY, chosenDiameter, separatorSize, canvasWidth, canvasHeight;
protected int tokenAtPos;

public BuildGame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initialise();
}
```

PlacedShips and HitOrMiss are essentially the same snippet apart from the name:

```
public class PlaceShips extends BuildGame {

private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private int placedShipNo = 0;

public PlaceShips(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());

    //GameplayListenerStuff
    BattleshipGameBase.BattleshipGameListener mGameplayListenerPS = new BattleshipGameBase.BattleshipGameListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGameChanged(BattleshipGameBase game, int column, int row) {
            System.out.println("onGameChangedPS");
            invalidate();
        }
    };
    mGame.addOnGameChangeListener(mGameplayListenerPS);
}
```

Comment: "without using static" for variables or even without static methods?

Comment: Create a single instance of `mGame` and inject it through the constructor of `PlaceShips` and `HitOrMiss` so that they share the same instance.

Comment: @0X0nosugar just variables in this case.

Comment: @AndrewS So this new instance would have to be in a different class to all the other classes?

Comment: Maybe you need to use the Singleton pattern, take a look at this [blog post on Medium](https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0)

Comment: Probably somewhere in the start up code up of the app, near the class(es) which create the `PlaceShips` and `HitOrMiss` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out using a setter and getter method for `mGame` was the answer, and setting the mGame of HitOrMiss to that of PlacedShips, in the activity. Doing it in either of the child classes didn't work.

It also turns out that the way I created the listeners was wrong, which wasn't helping.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you want the same `mgame` object in your `PlaceShips` and `HitOrMiss` objects?

You could make it like this:
`BuildGame`:

```
public class BuildGame extends View {
    protected final BaseSubClass mGame;
    //...

    public BuildGame(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, BaseSubClass mGame) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.mGame = mGame;
        initialise();
    }
}
```

`PlaceShips` and comparable  `HitOrMiss`:

```
public class PlaceShips extends BuildGame {
    //...

    public PlaceShips(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, BaseSubClass mGame) {
        super(context, attrs, mGame);
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureListener());

        //GameplayListenerStuff
        //...
        mGame.addOnGameChangeListener(mGameplayListenerPS);
    }
}
```

Now, when you create a new `PlaceShips` object or `HitOrMiss` object, you have to give a `BaseSubClass` as third argument. To have same mGame in a `PlaceShips` object and `HitOrMiss` object:

```
//...
BaseSubClass mySharedObject = new BaseSubClass(10, 10, BattleshipGameBase.ShipData.CREATOR.newArray(5));
PlaceShips ships = new PlaceShips(getApplicationContext(), myAttributeSet1, mySharedObject);
HitOrMiss hitOrNo = new HitOrMiss(getApplicationContext(), myAttributeSet2, mySharedObject);
//...
```

Comment: Hi @Sebastiaan, I tried you method however it caused inflation exceptions at runtime. I figured out the solution today. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh how sad, but nice that you got it working now! On a sidenote: I believe it might be better to use some kind of game framework (e.g. Unity or something like that) to build games. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Oh you're most likely right! This is being done as part of a unit I am studying so we are limited to using Android Studio.